# how to set a background picture on a JPanel and change the picture

Tags: java, user-interface

So in my project i'm trying to make something like a photo album, in which you can change the picture shown by clicking on a next button or previous button..

I saved some .png files in a LinkedList and tried to call each one when ever the method slideChanger() is called. however it doesn't work and i don't know why.

The method i'm using to set a background picture is by adding a JLabel containing the picture to my panel.

To fix my problem i tried removing the previous JLabel from the panel each time the method is called, but it also didn't work.

In following you can see the methods i wrote, in result of this code the program is only showing the first picture no matter how many times i call the method slideChanger().

```
LinkedList<Image> slides = new LinkedList<Image>();
public void loadTheorySlides()
{
     try 
     {
         for (int i=1;i<=14;i++)
         {
             Image slide = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage("W:\\workspace\\PeriodicSys\\TheorySlides\\Capture"+String.valueOf(i)+
                     ".png"); 
             slides.add(slide);
         }
     } 
     catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
}

int slideNum=-1;
public void slideChanger()
{

    slideNum++;
    JLabel background=new JLabel(new ImageIcon(slides.get(slideNum)));
    background.setSize(994, 591);
    background.setLocation(0, 0);
    pnlTheory.remove(background);
    pnlTheory.add(background);
    refreshPage();
}

public void refreshPage()
{

    frame.revalidate();
    frame.repaint();
    frame.validate();
}
```

How can i fix this guys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
JLabel background=new JLabel(new ImageIcon(slides.get(slideNum)));
```

Don't create a new label.

Instead just change the Icon of the label:

```
background.setIcon( new ImageIcon(slides.get(slideNum)) );
```

Then there is not need to remove/add the label to the frame.